# FontAwesome icons as squares on my website

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use Font Awesome for one of my projects.
on localhost the icons are working but on-site are shown as squares

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css">

<i class="fab fa-2x fa-react mr-3"></i>
<i class="fab fa-2x fa-css3-alt mr-3"></i>
```

I guess the problem is the font-family, everything was working fine before I decided to import Montserrat for my project

I have to use this font, can't change it.
Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: the font awesome apply a more specific selector (using class) so I don't think it's the issue

Comment: If it works without it, I would still check if `html { font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; }` fixes it.